# beautifulsoup: Dropping text inside tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract strings from a html file using beautifulsoup. A query replies with label tags inside them, how can I get rid of those tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('/Desktop/filename.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

string = soup.find('div', class_="col-sm-8 col-xs-6")
print(string)
```

Output-

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
    Sherlock Holmes <br>
    <label for="AgentAddress" style="display: none;">
        Detective's Address
    </label>
    221B Baker Street London <br>
    <label for="AgentCityStateZip" style="display: none;">
        City, State, Zip
    </label>
    London, United Kingdom            
</div>
```

`print(string.text)` outputs

```
    Sherlock Holmes
    Detective's Address
    221B Baker Street London
    City, State, Zip
    London, United Kingdom
```

I am not interested in the text inside the `<label></label>` tags, how can I get rid of them so that the output is-

```
    Sherlock Holmes
    221B Baker Street London
    London, United Kingdom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with decompose, example, before the print use this:

```
for label_element in string.find_all("label"):
    label_element.decompose()
```